# Insightful books on probability?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, reference-request, book-recommendation

Thanks for reading - this is a book recommendations question. I'm looking for books that deal with probability conceptually.

For example, I'd like books that address questions like:

1. ***Why*** can we make "so and so" assumptions when we use "some" probability model?
2. *What **assumptions** does the **Poisson** make about events, and why do they make sense?*
3. *What really **is** the probability of an event occurring? Does the definition change depend on the situation*
4. *Are probabilities total number of **successes** divided by total number of **trials**?*
5. *Are they the number of **"equally likely" things** that can happen (whatever "equally likely" means) divided by the **total number of things** that can happen in some situation?*
6. *What **are** probabilities?*

Additionally, questions like:

1. *When should we apply "so and so" probability model, and **why** does it make sense to apply it here?*

*Note that the "why" is bolded - that's the most important part.*

It can be mathematically rigorous *(although if it's more philosophical that's fine too)*, but at the same time, I'm looking for a book that analyzes the conceptual underpinnings of probability theory intuitively.

Thanks!

Comment: Part 1 of All of Statistics by Wasserman is good. If you want a bit more measure theory, Knowing the Odds By Walsh is good. If you want a very theoretical perspective (probably not much intuition), Probability and Measure by Billingsley is good.

Answer (score 1):

Good Thinking, by I.J. Good is a great book for you. The author analyzes the conceptual underpinnings of probability theory and brings a philosophical perspective to the theory. There is also a focus on applications.

A little about the author, who worked with Alan Turing at Bletchley Park:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I._J._Good

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1240327)

Comment: The OP asked for an insightful book and I gave them one. How does it not provide an answer?

Comment: It is only my opinion, but you could explain *why* the book is good for him, for example.